# Angular 2 application is running on local but not working while running ec2

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services

Angular 2 application is running on local but not working  while uploading aws ec2 t2.small instance.But it is working successfully in local server

node:v7.0.0

npm :3.10.8

```
   EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: 'timetables' with id='3' not found Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: 'timetables' with id='3' not found
```

Comment: what is the error you getting ?

Comment: Fix the error in line 51. I deducted that from the error details in your question.

Comment: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: 'timetables' with id='3' not found
Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: 'timetables' with id='3' not found

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anular cli , build your app with command `ng build --prod -aot`

then you need a server let me assume you are using express , you can serve index.html by express view engine and put all your js css build in angular in public folder .

Comment: we are currently using seed project

Comment: you need to find the way to build your app for production mode.